# How to block a PIN on sim/uicc

Tags: at-command, modem, umts, pin-code

I try to automate some tests, and the tests shall verify the unblocking of the pin, but to repeat the test, the pin should be blocked again.

I can't find a way (except reset) to block the pin again.
Even the specs like ETSI TS 102 221, mentions only how to unblock,enable, disable the pin.

**Why the hell something simple as block/logout isn't described anywhere?**

Reset works (a modem reset, by `AT!RESET`), but it's very slow and seems to be a nasty solution (Nowadays, it's even possible to logout from windows without restarting the PC).

**Additional informations:** I hoped for a general solution with a standard modem command or at least with a standard SIM command like `AT+CSIM=...`.
But it seems there aren't any, so the solution depends on the modem/manufacturer.

In my case I'm using a Sierra EM7565

Comment: I would probably be able to help you... but it is difficult during Christmas holiday without a module in my desk. In the meanwhile: what's wrong with reset? It usually takes about 1s to complete it.

Comment: @Cubo78 That would be great. Currenty I'm not at work, too. But your comment make me rethink of my reset. (I'm on a Linux system) Currently I reset the modem, that results into temporarily disappearing the device `/dev/ttyUSB2` and reappearing after some seconds, probably some service is involved there. But when I only reset the sim card that problem shouldn't occur

Comment: Hw resetting your sim card, if you have access to those pins (GPIOs?), will probably be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are right when you say that the specification never describes a standard way to set *PIN pending* status again in the SIM used by a cellular modem

The recommended solution is a reset of the modem. When you write

> Reset works, but it's very slow and seems to be a nasty solution
>   (Nowadays, it's even possible to logout from windows without
>   restarting the PC).

you probably refer to the *host PC* reset, and I agree that it might bee to slow. But you are not required to reset the host as long as you can reboot the modem.

You could either

- Remove its power supply, and this for sure will remove SIM's power supply as well. This depends of course on the way your device is connected to the host.
- Provide an AT command for the device reboot. Usually all vendors have a custom command performing this action. For example Telit modules support command `AT+REBOOT` that reboot both modem and SIM status.

---

### A creative solution: +CFUN=4/+CFUN=1

I tried to find another solution on two of my Telit modems, belonging to GE910 and LE910 families. Only for the first one it worked. For this reason **I cannot guarantee it will work for every cellular modem in the world**.

As explained in the title, the solution consists in providing in sequence

```
AT+CFUN=4
AT+CFUN=1
```

`+CFUN` command sets the phone functionality. The first command switches off RF, the second one restores full functionality mode.

But `+CFUN=4` command is commonly used as some sort of power saving mode, so that powering off the SIM provides a further power consumption reduction. This is what happens in my GE910-QUAD module.

For this reason it might work also for the uspecified device you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Currently I do a modem reset, but that is slow, as on my Ubuntu this results into a removal of the /dev/ttyUSBx and after some time the device is coming back. I hoped that there exists at least a general way to reset only the SIM, but Monday I will try your `AT+CFUN=4/1` tip.

Comment: Telit modules actually do have some way to reset the SIM, through custom commands. I omitted them because I was trying to provide a solution using only standard commands.

Comment: Your solution `AT+CFUN=4` followed by `AT+CFUN=1` doesn't work with my modem. But you pointed me to the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the Sierra EMEM7565 modem.
Selecting the secondary SIM interface disables the power for the first interface.
This is effectivly a reset for the SIM card.

```
AT!UIMS=1   -- Select active SIM interface 1
... wait 1 second
AT!UIMS=0   -- Select active SIM interface 0
```

It can also achieved by

```
AT+CFUN=0   -- Power Down Sim
AT+CFUN=1   -- Power Up Sim
```

but this only works, when the `SIM power state during Low Power Mode`
is configured to `2 = Power down SIM with AT+CFUN=0;`.
That can be done by
`AT!CUSTOM="SIMLPM",2` but requires also that the *access to password-protected commands* was enabled before with `at!entercnd="<pwd>"`.

Therefore, the solution with `AT!UIMS=1` followed by `AT!UIMS=0` seems the better one.

Comment: I understand. Anyway using custom commands (I was trying to use standard ones) there's a 100% working solution also for Telit devices, using #SIMDET comnand. I will update my answer tomorrow.